# SQL Server, double insert at the exact same time, unicity Bug

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

I am facing trouble when the following code is called two times almost at the same time.

```
DECLARE @membershipIdReturn as uniqueidentifier=null
SELECT @membershipIdReturn = MembershipId 
FROM [Loyalty].[Membership] 
WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ContactId = @customerIdFront 
AND 
IsDeleted = 0

IF (@membershipIdReturn IS NULL)
  //InsertStatementHere
```

The calls are so close (about 3 thousandth of a second), that the second call also enter inside the if statement. Then an unicity failure is lift because this is not supposed to happen.

Is the bug because of the `(NOLOCK)`? I need it for transaction issues.

Is there any workaround for correcting this behavior ?

Thanks Al

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying
[[[SELECT MembershipId FROM [Loyalty].[Membership] WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ContactId = @customerIdFront AND IsDeleted = 0]]]

is not NULL, but your IF statement evals to true after this is run?

Comment: Both statements are run almost at the same time. With a normal behaviour, only the first run should valid the if statement, the second should not be true, because an was already done by the first run. But since the calls are so close of each others, both run enter the if statement. Thanks, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options

1.Use unique constraint then put your insert statement in Try Catch block

```
ALTER TABLE [Loyalty].[Membership] 
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_ContactId_IsDeleted UNIQUE(ContactId, IsDeleted)
```

2.Use Merge with serializable hint. Therefore, there will be no gap between select and insert.

```
MERGE   [Loyalty].[Membership] WITH (SERIALIZABLE) as T 
USING   [Loyalty].[Membership] as S
ON      ContactId = @customerIdFront 
        AND IsDeleted = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (MemberName, MemberTel) values ('','');
```

Comment: There is already a constraint on contactId and Isdeleted, that's why a unicity faillure is lift. As i said for Aushin : 
 
Both statements are run almost at the same time. With a normal behaviour, only the first run should valid the if statement, the second should not be true, because an was already done by the first run. But since the calls are so close of each others, both run enter the if statement. Thanks for your answear tough, i m going to try the second option (merge). Will it affect performances ? Thanks AL